# How to get the reference of the KotlinNativeTarget object that I have instantiate from a kotlin{} block, to use it on another task?

Tags: gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to create a gradle plugin, to handle my kotlin-native project(s). Since I am reusing part of the logic, the obvious thing to do is to create a stand-alone plugin.

The problem is that my logic depends on the `KotlinNativeTarget` object that gets created inside the `kotlin` block, in order to get the current target architecture, operating system etc. Thus I am wondering how should I be able to transfer the reference of this object to my own task, in an elegant way.

I'd expect the `kotlin` block to add some parameters and/or propertied on the project itself, but when I tried to dig it in, there was an absolute chaos of objects and data and everything, which you can easily get lost if you don't know what you're looking at.

On the other had the documentation on kotlin multi-platform is much sparse and most of the time deprecated.. so no luck there. So, please, any hints are welcome!